# Why do I get int64 when creating itensor3 in Theano?

Tags: theano

I'm quite new to Theano, 
I'm trying to create a tensor of int32 using itensor3,but for some reason I get int64 instead of int32.
Do I need to specify anything in the config file?

```
from theano import tensor as T
l=T.itensor3()
k=l.shape[0]
f=theano.function([l],k)
inp=numpy.zeros((2,3,4), dtype=numpy.int32)
f(inp)
>>>array(2L, dtype=int64)
```

Comment: How do you know you've got int64? What code are you using? More information please!

Comment: Are you sure it's `itensor3` and not `ltensor3`? The `i` and `l` might easily be confused.

Comment: Yep, I used itensor3, I shared a simple example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Theano I believe shapes are always specified in `int64` values.

The result of your Theano function, `f`, is a shape size, i.e. `l.shape[0]` so the type of the result returned by `f` is going to be `int64`. This does not change the fact that the input is of type `int32`.